# Why my multithreading program still runs even though I am doing join?

Tags: java, multithreading

My program still runs even though I am doing join for each Thread in the main.
Also clearly my thread methods do not have any infitite loop. Then what can be the reason?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    PrimeCentral pc = new PrimeCentral();

    Thread one = new Thread(new PrimeAcceptor(pc), "Acceptor1");
    Thread two = new Thread(new PrimeAcceptor(pc), "Acceptor2");
    Thread three = new Thread(new PrimeGenerator(pc, 50), "Generator");
    one.start();
    two.start();
    three.start();

    one.join();
    two.join();
    three.join();
}
```

1st Thread run method

```
public void run() {
      int n=bound;
      while (n > 1) {
         int d;
         for (d=2; d <= n/2; d++) 
            if ((n % d) == 0) break; 
         if (d > n/2) {
            primeCentral.put(n);
            System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " puts " + n);
         }
      n--; 
      }

}
```

second Thread class run method

```
public void run() {
      while (true) {
          int prime = primeCentral.get();
          System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " gets " + prime);
          if (prime <= 2) break; 
      }

}
```

Prime Central

```
public class PrimeCentral {
    private int prime;
    private boolean available = false;


    public synchronized void put(int n){
        while(available){
            try{
                wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
        prime = n;
        available = true;
        notifyAll();        
    }

    public synchronized int get(){
        while(!available){
            try{
                wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
        available = false;
        notifyAll();
        return prime;
    }

}
```

Console output:

```
Thread Acceptor2 gets 47
Thread Generator puts 47
Thread Generator puts 43
Thread Acceptor2 gets 43
Thread Generator puts 41
Thread Acceptor1 gets 41
Thread Acceptor2 gets 37
Thread Generator puts 37
Thread Generator puts 31
Thread Generator puts 29
Thread Generator puts 23
Thread Acceptor2 gets 31
Thread Acceptor2 gets 23
Thread Acceptor2 gets 19
Thread Acceptor1 gets 29
Thread Generator puts 19
Thread Generator puts 17
Thread Acceptor1 gets 17
Thread Acceptor2 gets 13
Thread Generator puts 13
Thread Generator puts 11
Thread Acceptor2 gets 11
Thread Acceptor1 gets 7
Thread Generator puts 7
Thread Acceptor1 gets 5
Thread Generator puts 5
Thread Generator puts 3
Thread Acceptor1 gets 3
Thread Acceptor2 gets 2
Thread Generator puts 2
```

Comment: "...methods do not have any infinite loop."  Really?  What do you think `while(true)`{} is?  Maybe you're assuming the break is called in all cases.

Comment: how does `PrimeCentral` look, what does the console output look like.

Comment: @MadConan well, why it would not be called in all cases? As soon as prime <= 2 then it breaks

Answer (score 0):

That's because [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html) merely makes one thread for the completion of another thread. So if you call `one.join`, it makes the other threads wait for the completion of `one`. You are simply making the threads execute in order.

What is it exactly that you want your program to behave like instead?